# Redo a previous commit on local Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to cherry-pick commits from last week. I need to pick commits to reinstate and leave subsequent commits the way they are.

Someone told me this is possible with the checkout tool...

```
git checkout 531a4e247710ef09f80d8befbc4d2cfd
git branch -l
* (HEAD detached at 531a4ex)
  main
git commit -am 'commit an old commit'
```

At this point it just tells me

```
nothing to commit - working tree clean
```

Shouldn't the old commit - which isn't reflected in the current main - be something new to commit?

Any ideas here?

Comment: The advice you got was either bad or misunderstood. If you want to cherry-pick, do cherry-pick. Re-checkout your branch, and use `git cherry-pick <hash>` with the `<hash>`  of your commit. You can give more than one hash, they'll be sequentially picked (see [doc for the sequencer subcommands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_sequencer_subcommands)).

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER:

Thanks to @Romain Valeri for pointing out that the correct answer here is to use the cherry-pick git function...

"git cherry-pick is a powerful command that enables arbitrary Git commits to be picked by reference and appended to the current working HEAD. Cherry picking is the act of picking a commit from a branch and applying it to another. git cherry-pick can be useful for undoing changes."

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick

eg.

```
# find your branch
git branch -l 

# list your previous commits
git log

# cherry-pick the commit reference you'd like to apply to head on your current branch
git cherry-pick commitSha
```

Comment: Just `<branch>`? For unspecified "commits from last week"? Which branch?

Comment: Thanks Romain, you don't specific branch in ```git branch -l``` it's a git command.